# SQL Syntax = Display Relations inside "one table" + one relation Table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I try to display department relations with one table for Department and one for the relations. Every Department can have several relations (unknown), at least one (called "none").

In this case:
tbl_Department *(Dep_ID, Dep_NAME)*
tbl_Relation *(Rel_ID, Rel_Child_ID [ForeignKey tbl_Department.ID], Rel_Parent_ID[ForeignKey tbl_Department.ID])*

I get the best result (until now) with:

```
Select Parent_Table.Dep_Name as Parent, Child_Table.Dep_Name as Child
FROM tbl_department as Parent_Table, tbl_department as Child_Table, tbl_relation
WHERE Parent_Table.Dep_ID = tbl_relation.Rel_Parent_ID  
AND Child_Table.Rel_Chil_ID =tbl_relation.Rel_Child_ID
```

Looks like:

> **Parent - Child**
>   none - CMDG
>   none - FUND
>   none - GSPT
>   GSPT - IT Support
>   IT-Support - IT Security
>   IT-Support - IT Admin
>   FUND - Analysis & Reporting

But that's not exactly what I was looking for. The aim is to have a well done structured result for a "loop" to "display the company structure".

I would like to have it ordered (by relation) and filled with blanks (for empty field/relations).

Something like that:

> **Parent - Child - Child - Child**
>   none - CMDG - null - null
>   none - FUND - null - null
>   none - FUND - Analysis & Reporting - null
>   none - GSPT - null - null
>   none - GSPT - IT Support - null
>   none - GSPT - IT Support - IT Admin
>   none - GSPT - IT Support - IT Security

Is there a way to get this from the Database (MySQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know of a way to do this and return an arbitrary number of columns, but if you know there is only 4 levels in departments (counting none), you can do the following:

```
select d1.Dep_Name, d2.Dep_Name, d3.Dep_Name, d4.Dep_Name
from tbl_department d1
join tbl_relation r1 on r1.Rel_Parent_ID = d1.Dep_ID
join tbl_department d2 on d2.Dep_ID = r1.Rel_Child_ID
left join tbl_relation r2 on r2.Rel_Parent_ID = d2.Dep_ID
left join tbl_department d3 on d3.Dep_ID = r2.Rel_Child_ID
left join tbl_relation r3 on r3.Rel_Parent_ID = d3.Dep_ID
left join tbl_department d4 on d4.Dep_ID = r3.Rel_Child_ID
where d1.Dep_Name = 'none'
```

Comment: It seems that is the best i get. An arbitrary solutions would be much better, but I have no clue, if there is some thing like that.